# If $\bar{S}$ has dimension $n-k$, then $|E / \bar{S}|= 2^{n-k}$

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

This question revolves around understanding a claim made in "Quantum Error Correction via GF(4) Codes".

**Background**

- $S \leqslant S^{\perp} \leqslant E$
- Where $E$ is the quantum error group, consisting of all elements of the form $\pm w_{1} \otimes \dots \otimes w_{n}$, $\pm i w_{1} \otimes \dots \otimes w_{n}$
- $S^{\perp} =${$u| u.s=0 \forall s \in S$}$= C_{E}(S)=${$e \in E| es = se \forall S$} is the subgroup of $E$ that specifies the undetectable errors. Every element of $S^{\perp}$ commutes with $S$ (clearly as it is the centralizer of $S$ in $E$)
- $S$ is the abelian subgroup of $S^{\perp}$ consisting of errors that have no effect on the encoded state.
- $\bar{E} = E/Z(E)$ where $Z(E)$ is the centre of $E$.
- $\bar{S}$ is a subspace of $\bar{E}$

---

**From the text**

$S$ decomposes $\mathbb{C}^{2^{n}}$ into orthogonal eigenspaces. So :
"in order for $S$ to act trivially on the code, the code must lie entirely in one of these eigenspaces. We also want $S^{\perp}$ to preserve the code, we take the code to be one of the eigenspaces $Q$.

To each eigenspace of $S$ there corresponds a homomorphism $\chi : S \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, under which each element of $S$ is mapped to the corresponding eigenvalue. Then $\chi$ is a \textit{character} of $S$ and $\chi(iI)=i$.

Every element $e \in E$ normalizes $S$, and so conjugation by $e$ induces an action on characters. Since $S^{\perp}$ commutes with $S$, elements of $S^{\perp}$ induce a trivial action on the characters. Any element outside $S^{\perp}$ negates the value of the character at each element of $S$ with which it anticommutes. In particular, it induces a nontrivial action on the characters and so $E/S^{\perp}$ acts faithfully.

It follows that the orbit of any given character must have size $E/S^{\perp}$. If $\bar{S}$ has dimensions $n-k$, then $E/S^{\perp}=2^{n-k}$. On the other hand there are $2^{n-k}$ characters of $S$ such that $\chi(iI)=i$, since the quotient of any two characters is a character of $\bar{S}$. Thus $E/S^{\perp}$ acts transitively. It follows that each eigenspace must have the same dimension, namely $2^{k}$."

---

**My Question**

In the last paragraph of the previous section it states that the orbit of any given character must have size $|E/S^{\perp}|$. This makes sense to me as the order of the orbit of $\chi$: $|O_{\chi}|=|E|/|E_{\chi}|$ where $E_{chi}$ is the stabilizer subgroup of $\chi$. We know that $S^{\perp}$ induces a trivial action on the characters, meaning that $S^{\perp}=E_{\chi}$. So $|O_{\chi}|=|E/S^{\perp}|$.

However, I can't seem to understand why "If $\bar{S}$ has dimension $n-k$, then $|E / \bar{S}|= 2^{n-k}$.

I don't fully understand where $\bar{S}$ comes into play here?